# When the Redstone update happens, will my existing worlds reflect the new version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Playing on PC, when the Redstone update happens will that make changes to my current worlds?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The update will change how existing redstone works. The update isn't changing the game's internal concept of which blocks are which, so existing blocks (including redstone dust "blocks") will simply start using the new behaviour.

The one thing that you will likely have a small bit of trouble with is finding Nether Quartz (used to build the sunlight sensor, for example), because that *is* a new block that is supposed to be found in the world. However, these will generate just fine in newly-generated Nether chunks, so you just have to go exploring to new parts of the Nether after the update to start finding Nether Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

If the way Redstone works is changed then maybe some of your things will stop working.
You will be able to use your old redstone with the new features though.

Answer (score 0):

Only things such as new ores would affect your current worlds. That would change chunk generation. However, new logic gates and stuff may or may not break your creations. You will be able to craft new items and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have built Redstone machines that utilized functionality that was removed in 1.5, your current world will simply be updated to use the new behavior automatically. However, Nether Quartz (the new ore) will only generate in unexplored Nether chunks. [Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snapshots#Minecraft_1.5_Snapshots_.26_Pre-releases) is a list of the new functionality and changes that will be implemented in 1.5.